# getIdentifier returns wrong number

Tags: java, android

My strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="input1_id">1000074</string>
    <string name="input2_id">1000073</string>
    <string name="output1_id">1000128</string>
    <string name="output2_id">1000131</string>
</resources>
```

Java

```
int connId = getResources().getIdentifier("input1_id", "string", getPackageName());
Log.d("connId", String.valueOf(connId));
```

Returns: `2131623994`.

Why doesnt it return `1000074`?

I tried making a `integers.xml` with these as integers and calling `getIdentifier()` with `Integer` but that also doesn't work.

I also tried adding "this." before `getResources()` and `getPackageName()` but no change.

`getPackageName()` returns the same as defined in my `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: `connId` is what you would use in place of an `R.string` identifier. It's not the actual value itself. You still need to retrieve the string resource like you would normally; e.g., `String value = getString(connId);`.

Comment: @MikeM. Thank you that makes sense and is the answer.